# Is there a way to change the state in redux outside the component tree inside another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I'm trying to code a react.js web application, I'm trying to implement a specific feature that requires me to change the state from a file outside a component(aka non-jsx file). Is this even possible?? How do you do it??

Here are some attempts that I've made:

Api script:

```js
import store from "./index.jsx";
import foo from "./actions.js";

const state = store.getState();
store.dispatch(foo("Hello world!"));
/*^^^ERROR^^^ Error message: state.dispatch is not a function*/
```

index.js:

```js
//Importing packages
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./redux/reducers/index.js";

//Redux configuration
export const store = createStore(reducers);

//Render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have found another issue in this code:
When I run the code there are no errors but when I run this function by pressing a button it gives me this error:

```
action of type "AUTH_SIGN_IN", the slice reducer for key "login" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.
```

Comment: you can try with `store.dispatch(foo("Hello world!"));`

Comment: I think that is what I said in the question but I appreciate it @Asif vora

Comment: Please provide more details. You can not `dispatch` using the `state` like this `state.dispatch(foo("Hello world!"));` you can `dispatch` using the `store`.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the store on a separate file (I usually have src/store.ts). You will be able to import your store on index.js (for the React provider) and you'll be able to import it outside React too and simply `store.dispatch(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can not `dispatch` using the `state` like this `state.dispatch(foo("Hello world!"));` you can `dispatch` using the `store`.
You can do like this way `store.dispatch(foo("Hello world!"));`.

**Example :**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as ReactRedux from "react-redux";
import * as Redux from "redux";

function onIncriment() {
  return {
    type: "INCRIMENT"
  };
}

const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCRIMENT": {
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const staticReducer = {
  counter: counterReducer
};

let store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({ ...staticReducer }));

function App() {
  return <div>Counter value : {store.getState().counter.counter} </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </ReactRedux.Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

store.dispatch(onIncriment())
```

Comment: Thanks but I have ran into another error. and I am currently trying to get help for that error after editing the code that you gave me.

Comment: Please provide a details regarding that error.